# Clarification of a Pandemic rule involving the Medic

Tags: pandemic

The rules of the French edition of Pandemic are a little unclear about the following game situation. Once a cure for a disease (let's say *blue*) has been found, at any point the Medic is in an infected city, what happens?

> *(a)* the city is instantaneously cleaned, or 
>   *(b)* the whole disease is wiped from the board?

The literal wording of the French rules may be construed to mean *(b)*, but after only one game like this, it seemed to make the game so easy to win that we felt it was obvious it had to be *(a)* instead.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I hadn't thought about it before, but the English rules could probably have been written a bit more precisely as well. However, your final interpretation is correct, i.e. cubes are only removed from the city the Medic is in.

From page 5 of the rules:

> if the Medic at any time ﬁnds herself in a city that contains cubes of a disease that has been cured, she may immediately remove all of those cubes.

"Those cubes" would refer only to the cubes in the city she is in.

Answer (score 5):

OK, so it occurred to me just to go check the [English rules](http://www.zmangames.com/boardgames/files/pandemic/Pandemic_Rules.pdf) on the internet:

> Also, if the Medic at any time finds herself in a city that contains cubes of a disease that has been cured, she may immediately remove all of those cubes.

This is clearer than the French translation, and corresponds to my option *(a)*.