# Does the Medic remove all cubes of cured diseases from the cities he travels through?

Tags: pandemic

Does the Medic remove all cubes of cured diseases from the cities he travels through? Let's say he:

- drives to one city (3 cured cubes)
- drives to another city (2 cured cubes)
- drives to another city (1 cured cube)
- drives to another city (1 cured cube)

does he remove all 7 cubes on the way or just at the last city?

Comment: Related: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/3280/clarification-of-a-pandemic-rule-involving-the-medic and http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/27927/medic-at-a-city-with-cured-disease/27929#27929

Comment: If you feel your question has been adequately answered (it seems so to me), then you might want to accept the given answer.

Answer (score 18):

All of the cubes. This is not an action.

> The Medic may remove all the cubes of a single color (instead of 1)
>   when performing the Treat Disease action. Also, if the Medic **at any
>   time** finds herself in a city that contains cubes of a disease that
>   has been cured, she may immediately remove all of those cubes.  This
>   unique ability is in effect during all players’ turns and does not
>   cost any actions to perform.

Emphasis mine.

Comment: This answers the question but its worth pointing out that "at any time" also includes when its not the medic turn.  So if the dispatcher moves the medic then the cubes are removed also.

Comment: @MildlyPerilous: I considered mentioning the double-medic tactic, but chose to leave it as a hint.